# How to use Excel ListBox for SQL Query parameters

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript, vba

I have to execute a SQL query on a database and analyse data into an Excel file.

The point is to put multiple parameters in a IN construct from a listbox.
I managed to create the listbox in Excel but I'm having problem *extracting data from it and putting it in the query*.

Do you know how to or do you have any reference to a guide?

Recap:

1. I have a listbox populated with data
2. I need to put multiple entries of the listbox as parameter of a SQL query (IN construct)
3. I don't mind use VBS or similar

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim lngRow As Long

strSQL = ""
For lngRow = 0 To frmUsers.lstUsers.ListCount - 1
    strSQL = strSQL & frmUsers.lstUsers.List(lngRow, 0) & ", "
Next lngRow
strSQL = "where SearchForUserCriteria in (" & Mid(strSQL, 1, Len(strSQL) - 2) & ") "
```